# Blender color grading on output file

Tags: rendering, color, file-format, .exr

I'm having color banding on my output file, but not on my render.

So you can see the render result:

[image: render result]

And my output file looks like this:

[image: this]

For the purpose of my post, the file format is in PNG 16bit, but even with OpenEXR Float Full (32bit i suppose), i get the same color banding.

I set the "dither" to 1.0.

I would like to know why I can get a similar result to my render result?

Thank you.

Comment: could be lots of reason. Providing an example blend file would help a lot

Comment: Since is for a commercial project, I can't share it, but the background where the color banding appears, is a plane, with a colorRamp set to Ease. When I apply a texture image instead, the color banding disapeared

Comment: Just provide the blend file only with the plane? Where is the problem? Delete the Rest. Or do you wanna tell me there is copyright on that plane with the Colorramp? I have more and more the feeling people using copyright reason because they are too lazy to share the blend file…